# printing elements of array in Pug

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I am new to Jade/Pug template engine used in Express
I need to print out the name property of a list objects contained in an associative array passed as parameter to the pug template from an express route module.

I am trying in different ways like

```
  each element in listOfElements
      p #{element.name}
```

where listOfElements is the name of the passed parameter

But I can't get the desired result

**UPDATE**

I am now trying to follow the doc which only provides a `UL` example (not what I need).

According to the doc I am going like this

```
ul
each element in listOfElements
    li = element.name
```

What I get on the rendered page is a list in which each bullet contains the " = element.name" text

Comment: https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: see the update thank you

Comment: It should be `li=` and not `li =`

Comment: wow I didn't get it is sensitive to white spaces. Post the answer

Comment: You can answer the question yourself. I would also want to know why the first one wasn't working.

Comment: which one? the one with 'p' ? it had to be 'p='. Are you asking to see if I got it ? :)

Comment: Yeah! The one with `p` should have also worked.

Comment: it works with 'p='. I just find strange 'p=' and 'p =' are different. Thank you for your kind help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going by the documentation on Pug website [regarding iterations](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html), you can get buffered code by placing an `=` right after the tag name. The docs for the same [lie here](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#buffered-code). Therefore, in your second attempt, the following will work:

```
ul
each element in listOfElements
    li= element.name
```

---

However, as to the first attempt, I tried the following code, and it gave me the expected output (as shown after the snippet):

```
ul
  each val in [{1:'a'}, {1:2}, {1:3}, {1:4}, {1:5}]
    li #{val[1]}
```

outputs:

```
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```